# What to use instead of form.factory on Symfony 2.8.2/3.0

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have this service in my bundle:

```
  oauth_server.authorize.form:
         class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
         factory: [createNamed, "form.factory"]
         arguments: ['@oauth_server.authorize.form_type', oauth_server_authorize
```

On Symfony 2.8.0 there is no such error but after 2.8.1 and 2.8.2 also on 3.0 i get this error:

```
Cannot dump definition because of invalid factory method (form.factory)' in...
```

I cannot find any documentation regarding to my problem and I have no idea how to overcome on this.

Which service or scheme should I use or follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the `factory` arguments. The first argument should be the class or service and the second argument should be the method to be called:

```
oauth_server.authorize.form:
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    factory: ['@form.factory', createNamed]
    arguments: ['@oauth_server.authorize.form_type', oauth_server_authorize]
```